# How to validate user input from UItextfield with Plist data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, plist

i had a Plist file which contains username and password.

- how to fetch data from Plist and Validate with user input values when ever the submit button is clicked.
- after submit button is pressed. if user input data matches with data in Plist. it should show Login successful and displays Profile data in Another View controller.

in Objective-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

**Swift**

// force unwrapped to assure existence of data

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "plist")  

let dic = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! [String:String]  

self.name = dic["username"] as! String

self.pass = dic["password"] as! String
```

when submit

check

```
if username.text == name && password.text == pass {
    // success
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSDictionary *mainDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"plist"]];

NSString *name = mainDictionary[@"username"];

NSString *pass = mainDictionary[@"password"];

if ([username.text isEqualToString:name] && [password.text isEqualToString:pass]) {

     // success
}
```

Comment: I'm about to post the answer and you just posted it :) +1 for it

Comment: @PPL thnks will keep it for you next time =D

Answer (score 0):

get plist is safe by

```
func getDictOfPlist(fileName : String) -> [String:String]? {
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "plist") else {
        // can't gen file path
        return nil
    }
    guard let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePlist) as? [String:String] else {
        // can't read file or data type false
        return nil
    }
    return dict
}
```

use in

```
    if let content = getDictOfPlist(fileName: "UserData") {
        username.text = content["name"]
        // ....
        // ....
    }
```

Comment: Question is tagged `objective-c`